# Webserver cannot connect by domain but can by IP

Tags: windows, server, webserver

i make a web server but i cannnot connect by domain but by IP it can connect
this is my domain fisip.unhas.ac.id and ip 103.195.142.43

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your DNS redirect.
All web server are accessible by IP,
Then, when you do a correct DNS redirect, you can access your website by the domain.

Check your DNS.